# Loop through delimited string in DB2

Tags: sql, loops, db2

I have a delimited string of values like such: 00,45,50,66,84,99.  This string is passed as an IN parameter to a DB2 stored procedure. In the procedure, I would like to loop through this string and insert each value into a temp table. My knowledge of DB2 looping syntax is very poor and I have been struggling with this for awhile. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Looping in SQL in general is usually a bad idea, although that usually refers to messing with table rows, not SPs.  Sticking it into a temp table may be problematic, though; I think I'd rather return a set of rows.  _Why_ do you have a delimited list of values?  If this is from an external source (eg query from a program), why not use an array (which most drivers support)?  If this is internal (eg a column in a table), you're probably better off normalizing the data to make it easier to query.

Comment: I'm using the delimited string as an alternative to using the IN function, which you can't apply to a delimited parameter. My goal, as a workaround, is to fill a temp table with the delimited values, then inner join it with my cursor results to act as a filter.

Comment: Most drivers/frameworks I'm aware of (for Java and C#, at least) will accept an array to be used for the list of values in an `IN()` clause.  What language is calling your statement, what _is_ the statement, what platform are you on, etc?  And I'd still caution you strongly against a temp table - what happens if you need to use the same function for two different sets of parameters?  In that vein, you could probably use a recursive CTE to split the string, although I think the SP would be the cleanest solution.

Comment: I am calling the procedure from a C# web application. The statement is huge, so I won't explain it all to you, but one particular parameter can have multiple values. Thus the need for the IN() clause. So if an array will work for this clause, what DB2 data type is used to receive the array as a parameter?

Comment: It looks like you must have DB2 v9.5 or later to get support for arrays as stored procedure parameters. I have version 8 something... Also, the array must be a fixed length, and my parameter will have a dynamic number of values. Dang! Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Your goal to use a temp table is probably the best solution.  Except make sure you the *client app* insert the rows into the temporary table and then call the stored procedure.  This will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a recursive SP that takes the IN varchar, processes the first element, and do a recursive call for the rest.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REC (
 IN STRING VARCHAR(256)
)
P_REC: BEGIN
 DECLARE INDEX SMALLINT;
 DECLARE PRE VARCHAR(256);
 DECLARE POS VARCHAR(256);
 DECLARE STMT STATEMENT;
 PREPARE STMT FROM 'CALL REC(?)';

 SET INDEX = POSSTR (STRING, ',');
 IF (INDEX <> 0) THEN
  SET PRE = SUBSTR(STRING, 1, INDEX - 1);
  INSERT INTO table
    VALUES (PRE);
  -- Recursive call
  SET POS = SUBSTR(STRING, INDEX + 1);
  EXECUTE STMT USING POS;
 ELSE
  INSERT INTO table
    VALUES (STRING);
 END IF;
END P_REC @
```

To make it work from db2clp:

```
db2 create table table (string varchar(256))
db2 -td@
 <Copy, paste> in the interactive mode + quit
db2 call rec ('00,45,50,66,84,99')
db2 select * from table
```

Comment: So if this SP is being called from my primary SP, and I make 'table' to be a temp table, can I access the temp table from my primary SP, such that I can perfrom a join? Thank you for help!

Comment: Sure, if you call this SP and then access the Temp table, all done in the same connection, you will not have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I use the advanced functions in XQuery.   You can use something like

```
SELECT    XMLQuery('$PORDER/PurchaseOrder/item/name'  PASSING porder AS "PORDER") 
FROM purchaseorder
```

and put complex XQuery expressions between the quotes.

You can then wrap it in XMLCAST to convert it back to a SQL datatype.   I recently did this to convert long hex strings to binary, as XQuery has a function for that.

```
 SELECT XMLCAST(XMLQuery( ....) AS VARCHAR(100)) .....
```